# When are the user meta fields created in the database? Admin vs Woo API REST

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm trying to save the initial value (saved_fname) of a new user created, when the registration is done from the admin panel it works but when I do it from REST API (Integromat) the user registers but the function doesnt work correctly. Same code, with no plugins installed.

Both methods, the function "saved_first_name" is executed but using REST API it is as if the values in the wp_usermeta table have not been registered yet, get_user_meta returns empty.

```
functions.php theme
function saved_first_name($user_id){
    $saved_fname = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'saved_fname', $saved_fname);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'imhere', 'yes');
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'saved_first_name' );
```

DB usermeta table result when registering user from admin panel:

- metakey: metavalue
- imhere: yes
- saved_fname:   user1
- first_name:        user1
- nickname:        user1

DB usermeta table result when registering user from API REST:

- metakey: metavalue
- imhere: yes
- saved_fname:   (empty-no value)
- first_name:        user2
- nickname:        user2

I can't find the reason for that behavior. Any suggestions are welcome & appreciated.

Comment: When creating users via the REST API, you should use the `first_name` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user) to set the user's first name. But why are you inserting another metadata holding the same value?

Comment: hi, user creation via rest api works correctly. Problem starts when saved_first_name function is executed, its as if it was executed before first_name value is saved in the DB. This is an example, my real case gives points to the user according to the size of their name, when I create the user from admin it works fine but not via rest api.

Comment: Can you show the code you use for making the REST API request? Because with the default endpoint (`/wp/v2/users`) and if your request include all the necessary user data, then your code should work fine.

Comment: the sad part is that I don't have the code that is used to request: create customer user cause I use Integromat and it connects via Woocommerce REST API
https://i.ibb.co/58RyNpZ/integromatwoo.png

Comment: I'd like to help you further, but I don't use Integromat, so you should contact them for assistance. Or if you could show the full request data like headers and body/content, then I might be able to give you some suggestions.